# Links not rendering correctly in question edit preview

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, markdown-preview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Links to URLs with square parentheses are not formatted in the preview, but rendered on the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81803/links-to-urls-with-square-parentheses-are-not-formatted-in-the-preview-but-rende)

Just a small bug with links rendering in question edit preview

**Edit pane:**
[image]

**Preview pane:**
[image]

**Viewing the question:**
[image]

Notice the link missing in the preview pane for the second link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires some rather hairy recursive-esque regular expressions to solve -- and nested matching is something they are quite bad at -- so it's unlikely it will ever be addressed in the javascript preview.

If the preview being off bothers you, you can of course escape the [ as `%5B` and the ] as `%5D`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, no it doesn't bother me, just wanted to point it out. Thanks.