# Links to URLs with square parentheses are not formatted in the preview, but rendered on the site

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown-preview

Example:

> [My posts in the minecraft tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:23+[minecraft])

Source:

```
[My posts in the minecraft tag][1]

  [1]: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:23+[minecraft]
```

The link is not rendered by the js markdown parser, although the link is rendered successfully when posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next build – you know the drill :)